# PocketSphinx android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmusphinx

I'm trying to use PocketSphinx in my project,

But I can't use it on Android Studio.

It has a version of .so files and a jar that has no libs, That is compatible with Eclipse, But not Android Studio.

Can you help me to find a version that will work or explain how I could use that version in Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually its compatible with Android Studio .Just create /lib folder under the root than copy the jar file in it. Than right click on the jar file and select "make it library" or something like this. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: It would work perfectly. "nolib" just means that jar doesn't include jni libraries, it has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: how to create dictionary and use in studio project

Answer (score 0):

Please check recently updated [tutorial for using Pocketsphinx on Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it includes a link to the Android Studio project in a section about Android studio. It should work out-of-box.

Comment: how to make dictionary and put it in the project ,please guide